# Passing :id to Service

Tags: angular, typescript, wordpress-rest-api

Early Angular days for me, hopefully simple question.

I'm using the WordPress REST API and trying to display a list of posts from a category using [posts?categories={ID HERE}](http://v2.wp-api.org/reference/categories/), my issue is that I'm not sure how to pass the ID from categories-list to posts-service.ts the component that will list the articles is called category-single.component.ts.

---

categories-list.component.html

```
<ul *ngFor="let category of categories">
  <li><a (click)="selectCategory(category.id)">{{category.name}}</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

---

categories-list.component.ts

```js
selectCategory(id) {
  this.router.navigate(['/category', id]);
}
```

---

app-routing.module.ts

```
{
  path: 'category/:id',
  component: CategorySingleComponent
}
```

---

posts.service.ts

```js
export class PostsService {

  private _wpBase = "http://base.local/wp-json/wp/v2/";

  constructor(private http: Http) {}

  getPostList(): Observable < Post[] > {

    return this.http
      .get(this._wpBase + `posts?categories={ID GOES HERE}`)
      .map((res: Response) => res.json());

  }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once you redirect to desire route, you need to **fetch route parameter** as shown below,

```
export class CategorySingleComponent{

   constructor(  private route: ActivatedRoute,  
                 private router: Router,
                 private postsService : PostsService  ) {}

   ngOnInit() {
     this.route.params.forEach((params: Params) => {
        let id = +params['id']; // (+) converts string 'id' to a number
        // this.postsService.getPostList(id).subscribe()...
      });
   }


}
```

---

Also,

```
getPostList(id:number): Observable < Post[] > {        //<<<===changed

    return this.http
      .get(this._wpBase + `posts?categories={ID GOES HERE}`)
      .map((res: Response) => res.json());

}
```

Comment: Legend! Seems to be working for me now. Does this look correct to have in category-single.component.ts?

  <code>`getPostList(id){
    this.postsService
      .getPostList(id)
      .subscribe(res => {
        this.posts = res;
      });


  }`</code>

   <code> `ngOnInit() {
      this.route.params.forEach((params: Params) => {
        let id = +params['id']; // (+) converts string 'id' to a number
         this.getPostList(id);
      });`</code>

Comment: what is this? what does `getPostList(id)` do in `categorysinglecomponent.ts`?

Comment: getPostList(id) will remain in `PostsService` service. aprat from this FYI to write code in comment , you can use backtick from keyboard. you don't need to use `<code>` tag.

Comment: Moreover if it solves your problem, you can accept the answer so it will be helpful for future readers. I'm telling you this because it seems your are new to stackoverflow.

Comment: getPostList is supposed to get the response from posts.services.ts so I can go: 


`<ul *ngFor="let post of posts">
    <li>{{post.id}}</li>
</ul>`

I forgot to add, I have `posts: Post[];` in my category-single.component.ts. Apart from that, thank you very much for the above code, opened my eyes to code I haven't learnt!